# Wrapping text nodes with span's, and inner-text nodes with spans if new text appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a simple application where you change the colors of each letter in a paragraph.

Right now, I use lettering.js to wrap the default text with spans, which is easy, but not when each span has `contenteditable` and I'd like to wrap the new text nodes with spans when it's out of focused.

So for example, let's say I'd like to wrap each text node in this phase with a span.

```
<div aria-label="Username" class="text">
    <span class="char4">U</span>
    <span class="char5">s</span>
    <span class="char6">e</span>
    <span class="char7">r</span>
    <span class="char8">n</span>
    <span class="char9">a</span>
    <span class="char10">m</span>
    <span class="char11">e</span>
    <span class="char12"></span>
    <span class="char13"></span>
</div>
```

That's done, but what if there is new letters?

outputted with lettering.js

```
<div aria-label="Username" class="text">
    <span class="char4">U</span>
    <span class="char5">srrw</span>
    <span class="char6">eww</span>
    <span class="char7">r</span>
    <span class="char8">nw</span>
    <span class="char9" style="color: red;">arww</span>
    <span class="char10">mer</span>
    <span class="char11">eee</span>
    <span class="char12"></span>
    <span class="char13"></span>
</div>
```

Notice the new style attribute and more letters in each node. Each letter can change a color and with contenteditable, you can add more text.

Now, I can re-use lettering.js like so:

```
function setTextNodes() {
    $(".text").lettering();
}
```

But that REMOVES the style attribute from the text node that was changed. So, I'm hoping expected results should be like this:

```
<div aria-label="Username" class="text">
    <span class="char4">U</span>
    <span class="char5">s</span>
    <span class="char6">e</span>
    <span class="char7">r</span>
    <span class="char8">n</span>
    <span class="char9" style="color: red;">a<span>w</span><span>w</span></span>
    <span class="char10">m</span>
    <span class="char11">e</span>
</div>
```

So:

1. Wrap default letters with spans (done)
2. Select a letter, add contenteditable to the span and change its color (done)
3. if more letters were added, wrap those letters with `<span>`'s as well, BUT keep the styling (lettering.js does not do)
4. I should be able to also edit those text new text nodes as well (click event on them)

How can I do this?

Here is what I got so far. There is a color palette you can use to change the color.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVgoZa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match your needs, the important thing is that a just edited (and colored) character (or set of characters) must be again transformed like `lettering()` does.

So the solution is to change your `setTextNodeColor()` function like this:

```
  function setTextNodeColor(selectedColorElem){
    var colorName = selectedColorElem.data('color'),
        $oldSet = $('.selected');
    $($oldSet.lettering().html())
      .css('color', colors[colorName].hex)
      .replaceAll($oldSet);
  }
```

It replaces the current `<span>` with a "lettered" set of `<span>`s, then applies the choosen color.
Note: this method causes `lettering()` to affect new classes from `char1` to `charN`, so this is a bit insconsistent. But in your peculiar case it don't matter, since you're not using them for CSS like it is usual with `lettering`.

Here is a [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWMpYV).